# Aspose - SVG Not shown correctly when I generate a file

Tags: svg, aspose

I've got the following SVG data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE svg>
   <svg width="900" height="600" viewBox="-60 -40 240 160" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <rect x="-60" y="-40" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fe0000"/>
      <rect x="-60" y="-40" width="50%" height="50%" fill="#000095"/>
      <path id="four_rays" d="M 8,0 L 0,30 L -8,0 L 0,-30 M 0,8 L 30,0 L    0,-8 L 
      -30,0" fill="#fff"/>
      <use xlink:href="#four_rays" transform="rotate(30)"/>
      <use xlink:href="#four_rays" transform="rotate(60)"/>
      <circle r="17" fill="#000095"/>
      <circle r="15" fill="#fff"/>
   </svg>
```

This graphic works correctly when opened in Windows 10 as a file, but when I try to load this graphic into a generated Word (.docx) file it shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ki3J.jpg), while it is supposed to look like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Flag_of_the_Republic_of_China.svg). All other SVG files (they are also flags) I load into my Word (.docx) file work like they should, this is the only exception.

Could someone tell me what is going on? It seems like the SVG data is identical.

Comment: We have logged this issue as WORDSNET-17416 in our issue tracking system. We will inform you once there is an update available on it. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @Tahir Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @Teije, the issue you had found earlier (filed as WORDSNET-17416) has now been fixed in [this Aspose.Words for .NET 19.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/19.3.0) update and [this Aspose.Words for Java 19.3](https://repository.aspose.com/repo/com/aspose/aspose-words/19.3/) update. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.